# Fluent with MySQL (MariaDB) Geometry column type

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

I need to retrieve latitude/longitude from MariaDB database stored as `POINT` data type and unable to find a solution for this.

I tried to read value as a string:

```swift
@Field(key: "location")
var location: String?
```

But it's not working (no wonder). The error I experience is:

> invalid field: location type: Optional error:
> typeMismatch(Swift.Optional<Swift.String>,
> Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Could
> not convert MySQL data to Optional: <MYSQL_TYPE_GEOMETRY>",
> underlyingError: nil))

Could please someone share with me any examples/conversion logic how this value could be processed?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have a look at how it's done for Postgres in the PostGIS library https://github.com/brokenhandsio/fluent-postgis

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any support in fluent/mysql for POINT, currently. Without modifying the fluent sources, you could use a raw query to extract the x and y values as floats or the whole POINT value as a hex string and post-process. Alternatively, it doesn't look too onerous to add your own data-type, decoder and encoder.